# Dynamic variables in systemd service unit files

Tags: systemd, configuration, services

Is there a way to dynamically assign environment variables in a systemd service unit file?

We have a machine that has 4 GPUs, and we want to spin up multiple instances of a certain service per GPU. E.g.:

- gpu_service@1:1.service
- gpu_service@2:1.service
- gpu_service@3:1.service
- gpu_service@4:1.service
- gpu_service@1:2.service
- gpu_service@2:2.service
- gpu_service@3:2.service
- gpu_service@4:2.service
- ad nauseam

So the 1:1, 2:1, etc. are effectively the %i in the service unit file.

In order for the service to bind to a particular GPU, the service executable checks a certain environment variable, e.g.:

```
USE_GPU=4
```

Is there a way I can take %i inside the service unit file and run it through some (shell) function to derive the GPU number, and then I can set the USE_GPU environment variable accordingly?

Most importantly, I don't want the hassle of writing multiple `/etc/systemd/system/gpu_service@x:y.service/local.conf` files just so I can spin up more instances.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you are careful you can incorporate a small bash script sequence as your exec command in the instance service file. Eg

```
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'v=%i; USE_GPU=$${v%:*} exec /bin/mycommand'
```

The `$$` in the string will become a single `$` in the result passed to bash, but more importantly will stop `${...}` from being interpolated by systemd. (Earlier versions of systemd did not document the use of `$$`, so I don't know if it was supported then).

Comment: I ended up doing something like that. :)

Comment: Call a `bash -c` to start a program from the unit file? Call `exec`? This is like using a forklift on top of a forklift (maybe with another forklift on top) because the first forklift has trouble actually forklifting.

Comment: Something like this would work. Or a wrapper script to split that variable :) The other bizarre option would be to create another service to "run beforehand" and setup an EnvironmentFile, not sure how that would work with templates tho: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42841480/32453

Comment: @DavidTonhofer How would a solution without "double forklifter" look like? I see that the bash is there to setup and mangle `%i` into `USE_GPU`. Then `exec` replaces the shell process with the real one.

Answer (score 10):

No built in way. You need to do these things before your service starts. One way would be putting it to an environment file.

```
[Service]
# Note you need to escape percentage sign
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c "my_awesome_parser %%i > /run/gpu_service_%i"
EnvironmentFile=/run/gpu_service_%i
ExecStart=...
```

Comment: Unfortunately you can't use an ExecStartPre to write an env file, then use it, apparently it has to be written beforehand.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you can indeed set environment variables inside a systemd unit file...

Per suggestions from  commenters, here is the solution:

> ## Using environment variables in systemd units
>
> ### Environment directive
>
> systemd has an Environment directive which sets environment variables for executed processes. It takes a space-separated list of variable assignments. This option may be specified more than once in which case all listed variables will be set. If the same variable is set twice, the later setting will override the earlier setting. If the empty string is assigned to this option, the list of environment variables is reset, all prior assignments have no effect. Environments directives are used in built-in Container Linux systemd units, for example in etcd2 and flannel.
>
> With the example below, you can configure your etcd2 daemon to use encryption. Just create `/etc/systemd/system/etcd2.service.d/30-certificates.conf` drop-in for etcd2.service:
>
> ```
> [Service]
> # Client Env Vars
> Environment=ETCD_CA_FILE=/path/to/CA.pem
> Environment=ETCD_CERT_FILE=/path/to/server.crt
> Environment=ETCD_KEY_FILE=/path/to/server.key
> # Peer Env Vars
> Environment=ETCD_PEER_CA_FILE=/path/to/CA.pem
> Environment=ETCD_PEER_CERT_FILE=/path/to/peers.crt
> Environment=ETCD_PEER_KEY_FILE=/path/to/peers.key
> ```
>
> Then run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` and `sudo systemctl restart etcd2.service` to apply new environments to etcd2 daemon.

Quoted text taken from the following URL:
https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/using-environment-variables-in-systemd-units.html

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, it would be [preferable to include the essential parts of the answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: While your comment may theoretically improve my future responses in stackexchange, it would be preferable for you to have included the essential parts of the answer in your comment instead of just commenting to point out how incompetent someone may be :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Thanks for the comment, you made me smile.  Also thanks for taking the time to edit your answer.  We are trying to build something that will have value over time, and link only answers just don't age very well.

Comment: If you add `Environment=ABC=%i` it does set that env. variable "to the entirety of %i". I guess you could make a wrapper to strip off the "stuff beyond the quote" you don't want, and it call the real executable. But if you're making a wrapper, you could even just pass `%i` in as an argument to it ex: `ExecStart=my_wrapper %i`

Comment: The question was for "dynamic" variables; you've simply given us the answer for the static solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's ugly and not quite what you asked for, nor does it allow for autostart, but for followers it is possible to do something using the systemctl [environment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/383436/8337):

```
$ sudo systemctl set-environment USE_GPU=4 # add it to the env. variables for future services
$ sudo systemctl start gpu_service@4:2.service
```

One problem is if you run/start more than one "at once" (in parallel) then it could cause confusion/race conditions.

Just trying to list all the options possible, some of the other answers work as well :)

Comment: +1: `ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c "/bin/systemctl set-environment USE_GPU=4"` is the best way to do this of the answers posted here.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `EnvironmentFile` directive which points to a env file with the variable. The file is created by an `ExecStartPre` command before the actual service is started. Your variable will be accessible in the `ExecStart` directive with `${GPU_COUNT}`.

```
[Unit]
Description=Dynamic variables in systemd units

[Service]
Type=simple
EnvironmentFile=-/tmp/gpu.env
ExecStartPre=sh -c 'printf "%%s\n" GPU_COUNT=$( (...) ) > /tmp/gpu.env'
ExecStart=(...)
ExecStartPost=sh -c 'rm /tmp/gpu.env'
```

You have to prefix the file path with `-`, which makes systemd ignore the fact that the file doesn't exist during the initial check. Later, the `ExecStartPre` command creates the env file. In another *unit state* the file location will be evaluated again (still before `ExecStart`), and if it exists, systemd will load the variables. Here's how `man systemd.exec` explains it:
`The files listed with this directive will be read shortly before the process is executed (more specifically, after all processes from a previous unit state terminated. This means you can generate these files in one unit state, and read it with this option in the next. The files are read from the file system of the service manager, before any file system changes like bind mounts take place).`

Comment: Are you sure about this? On my embedded system with systemd 251.8 `EnvironmentFile` is evaluated only before ExedStartPre and not repeated before ExecStart. Thus the env file is not read into env of ExecStart.

Comment: @Martin H. I have been running a few systemd services using this approach without issues, on Ubuntu x86 machines, with systemd 252.x at the time of writing the answer. The earliest accessible man page on freedesktop, which includes the quoted sentence, comes from systemd [247](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/247/systemd.exec.html).