# systemd, EnvironmentFile, re-using variables - how?

Tags: systemd, environment-variables

I am migrating from **upstart** to **systemd**. I am having a bit of trouble making the transition with the **EnvironmentFile** directive. I cannot get this **EnvironmentFile** to work:

```
########################################################
# Catalina Settings
CLUSTER_BASE=/d01/tomcat/prod/xyz
CATALINA_BASE=$CLUSTER_BASE/1
CATALINA_TMPDIR=$CATALINA_BASE/temp
CATALINA_HOME=/usr/share/tomcat7
CATALINA_PID=/run/tomcat/tc-prod-xyz-1.pid

########################################################
# Java Settings
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre
JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true
JAVA_OPTS=$JAVA_OPTS -server
JAVA_OPTS=$JAVA_OPTS -Xms2048m
JAVA_OPTS=$JAVA_OPTS -Xmx2048m
JAVA_OPTS=$JAVA_OPTS -XX:MaxPermSize=2048m
JAVA_OPTS=$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+UseParallelGC
JAVA_OPTS=$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+AggressiveHeap
JAVA_OPTS=$JAVA_OPTS -javaagent:$CLUSTER_BASE/newrelic/newrelic.jar
```

It would appear that this type of statement where I re-use a variable:

```
JAVA_OPTS=$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+UseParallelGC
```

is not supported in **systemd** like it was in **upstart**. Does **systemd** support something like this or do I need to make one long hard to read statement?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Unfortunately that file you have is actually a shell script. In the past, most init systems/scripts have interpreted files which provide environment variables by using the shell, so you could get away with doing shell things in them. Systemd however does not do this. The environment file is truly an environment file, not a script. This is documented in the [`systemd.exec` man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html):

> Variable expansion is not performed inside the strings, however, specifier expansion is possible. The $ character has no special meaning.

Therefore you have 2 options.

1. Expand out all your variables manually. Meaning use `CATALINA_BASE=/d01/tomcat/prod/xyz/1`.
2. Evaluate the file with the shell:
   `ExecStart=/bin/bash -ac '. /path/to/env_file; exec /path/to/program'`

Comment: Option #2 looks wrong.  `A=1`, `exec bash`, `echo $A` does not print `1`.  C.f. `export`.

Comment: @sourcejedi No, it's not wrong. See the `-a` argument. `man bash`: "Automatically mark variables and functions which are modified or created for export to the environment of subsequent commands."

Answer (score 4):

> Do I need to make one long hard to read statement?

No

> A line ending with a backslash will be concatenated with the following one, allowing multiline variable definitions.

Comment: So basically turn it into one very long "multiline" that works :)

Answer (score 2):

In the specific case of Tomcat (as in this question), I found that it is easier to put most of these settings in `bin/setenv.sh`, which is executed by Tomcat at startup, and evaluates the variables in the shell script as expected.

So in `/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service` I only specify the `Environment` variables for `CATALINA_BASE` and `CATALINA_HOME`, and then I put the rest of the stuff in `${CATALINA_BASE}/bin/setenv.sh`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use **bash** to expand your variables.

Environment file:

```
BLA=bla
BLABLA=${BLA}${BLA}
```

Use `bash -c` to execute the command:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c 'echo ${BLA} .. ${BLABLA}'
```

Output:

```
bash[4771]: bla .. blabla
```

Comment: This will only work in a very small number of (likely not to be used) cases. What's happening here is that systemd is actually running `bash -c 'echo bla ${BLA}${BLA}'`. So systemd is doing the first level of substitution, and then bash is doing the second level. If you're going to launch an application, that second level of substitution won't happen, and you'll be stuck with the variable `BLABLA=${BLA}${BLA}`.

Comment: It is possible to get second level substitution to work, FWIW, ex: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/324035/8337

Answer (score 0):

Another option: Have a secondary unit that runs before this one and creates an `EnvironmentFile` it can use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42841480/32453

The secondary unit can use bash for instance.  Seems to be the `systemd` way for importing env. :|