# Nested variables in systemd EnvironmentFile

Tags: systemd

```sh
#File: /home/miles/temp/foo.env

ONE=/one
TWO=${ONE}/two
FULL_PATH=${TWO}/three
```

```sh
#File: ~/.config/systemd/user/foo.service

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/home/miles/temp/foo.env

# prints ${TWO}/three
# ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'echo $FULL_PATH'

# prints ${ONE}/two/three
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'echo ${FULL_PATH}'
```

1. Is there a way to expand variables with an arbitrary level of nesting?

   It seems like it's only possible to expand **two** levels deep.

   Related: [How to get two levels of substitution working in EnvironmentFile](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/359005).
2. Why does adding curly braces around the `FULL_PATH` variable expand one level further?

   I'd expect curly braces to be optional in this case.

   > The parameter name or symbol to be expanded may be enclosed in braces, which are optional but serve to protect the variable to be expanded from characters immediately following it which could be interpreted as part of the name.

   https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

   In systemd, it looks like curly braces are only necessary to prevent splitting words on whitespace, which is not a factor in this example.

   > Use `"${FOO}"` as part of a word, or as a word of its own, on the command line, in which case it will be erased and replaced by the exact value of the environment variable (if any) including all whitespace it contains, always resulting in exactly a single argument. Use `"$FOO"` as a separate word on the command line, in which case it will be replaced by the value of the environment variable split at whitespace

   https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.service.html#Command%20lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key point here is a bit subtle, but it's there in the documentation you have quoted:

> Use "`${FOO}`" *as part of a word*, or as a word of its own,

> Use "`$FOO`" *as a separate word*

`$FOO` is expanded only when used as word by itself, but [the entirety of a quoted string is a word](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.syntax.html#Quoting), so `$FOO` inside a quoted string won't be expanded unless the string has only `$FOO` in it (so, `'$FOO'` or `"$FOO"`, but not `"something $FOO"`). Only `${FOO}` with braces will be expanded in a quoted string containing other text.

What you see is, therefore, systemd executing `/bin/sh -c 'echo ${TWO}/three'` in the case of `${FULL_PATH}`, and `/bin/sh -c 'echo $FULL_PATH'` in the case of `$FULL_PATH`.

In neither case is any component doing recursive variable expansion. In one case, systemd replaces `${FULL_PATH}` with `${TWO}/three`, and the shell then expands the `${TWO}`. In the second, systemd doesn't do any replacement, and the shell expands `$FULL_PATH`. I don't know of any way to safely expand a variable recursively.