# Pass an environment variable from current shell to a systemd unit

Tags: systemd, environment-variables

I am trying to pass an environment variable defined in the current shell to one of the `systemd` unit I am writing.

```
DB_URL=databus.dev.mysite.io:8080
```

I am using this in a python script which is running as a service. My `systemd` unit will run this script as a unit making use of the variable for its working.

```
[Unit]
Description=device-CompStatus: Computes device availability status
           
[Service]
Type=simple    
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/python /opt/deviceCompStatus/deviceCompStatusHandler.py"
Restart=always
         
[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

The way am using the variable in Python script would be

```
if os.environ.get('DB_URL') is not None:
    dbEndPoint = "http://" + os.environ['DB_URL']
```

The problem is am not able to use the variable when running the script in `systemd`. I looked up couple of resources [Using environment variables in systemd units](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/using-environment-variables-in-systemd-units.html), it says to use assignment under `[Service]` directly as

```
[Service]
Environment=DB_URL=databus.dev.mysite.io:8080
```

As you can see, my `DB_URL` could change depending upon the environment I am deploying my machine, it could be a developer, or a production setup, in which the URLs would vary.

How do I do this dynamically? i.e. pass whatever value available to `DB_URL` to `systemd` environment?

I also tried using the [`EnvironmentFile=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#EnvironmentFile=) option to define a file and pass it to service. But the same problem again, my variable could be dynamic and *cannot* be hardcoded.

#### Update

After using the option

```
systemctl import-environment DB_URL
```

I am able to see the variable available in the environment of `systemd` which I confirmed by

```
systemctl show-environment
DB_URL=databus.dev.mysite.io:8080
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

but still the value is not reflected in the `python` application which I run. Is `os.environ('DB_URL')` a wrong way to access the variable?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can affect the global systemd environment for all future commands (until reboot) by using

```
 sudo systemctl set-environment var=value
```

or if you already have `var` exported in your environment, you can use

```
 sudo systemctl import-environment var
```

After starting your unit you can remove the variable with `unset-environment` similarly.

As this is global in effect you would be better off simply writing the line `DB_URL=databus.dev.mysite.io:8080` into some file `/some/file` and setting `EnvironmentFile=/some/file` in your unit.

An alternative method is to use a template unit `myunit@.service` which is started with `systemctl start myunit@'databus.dev.mysite.io:8080'`. You can then recover this parameter as `%i` inside the unit, for example in the `[Service]` section with a line like:

```
Environment=DB_URL=%i
```

Comment: Great suggestions! Thanks! How do you suggest this for a file for the third option under `/some/file`? Assuming I define it as `IDB_URL=${IDB_URL}` in the file? Is that right where the RHS side is the environment variable and LHS would be the the variable I want to pass to `systemd`. How would this be passed to the unit?

Comment: The contents of the file are not evaluated. You cannot use bash-style variables in the RHS. You need to write the file with the real RHS value `databus.dev.mysite.io:8080` before starting the unit.

Comment: Fair point! But as I said before, my contents are dynamic, I cannot know the variable contents beforehand? So you suggest options 1) or 2) for this then?

Comment: Also an assignment like `sudo systemctl set-environment DB_URL=${DB_URL}` would be allowed to pass the environment to `systemd`?

Comment: Since the variable is in your current shell, you can simply `echo IDB_URL=${IDB_URL} >/some/file` at any time before starting the unit.

Comment: Great suggestions! if only I could double-vote! Will get back and _accept_ for sure and let know the working option! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Sorry for the detailed post, can you refer to the Update section of the question. I still can't get the `os.environ()` to load the imported variable in `systemd` environment?

Comment: It seems to work for me. The python should be ok. Remember the environment of `systemctl --user` is totally independent of the environment of `systemctl`, if you are mixing the two. Try dumping the environment whilst inside your `bash -c` execstart line (with the command `env`).

Comment: The way that the systemd people themselves would have us do this is to have a `.conf` file snippet, individual to each target platform and generated with `echo` into `/etc/systemd/system/deviceCompStatus.service.d`, that adds `Environment=DB_URL=development.example:8080` to the service unit.

Comment: @meuh: Accepting the answer, eventually was able to use the `EnvironmentFile` option to include the file containing the `DB_URL=<value>`. The more complexity was I was deploying the instance with Ansible, and had to fix a few trivial issues. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `sudo systemctl set-environment var=value` is exactly what I needed, thanks! Use `sudo systemctl show-environment` to check and `sudo systemctl unset-environment var` to undo.

Comment: Is there a pattern that allows inheriting an environment variable only for a specific unit, rather than 'globally'? My use-case is passing a security token to a unit that only that specific unit should see, rather than every unit.

Comment: @JesseAdelman, I don't know of one, sorry. A fairly heavyweight solution might be to set up a public key/private key encryption, encrypt the variable value and put it in the environment, and so only the unit knowing the private key could decrypt it.

Comment: @meuh Thanks for helping to confirm that what I seek can't easily be done. :)

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, 50-systemd-user.sh from systemd itself provides a way to import environment variables DISPLAY and XAUTHORITY which you can refer:

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                                                                                                                                                    

systemctl --user import-environment DISPLAY XAUTHORITY

if command -v dbus-update-activation-environment >/dev/null 2>&1; then 
    dbus-update-activation-environment DISPLAY XAUTHORITY
fi
```

https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/xorg/50-systemd-user.sh

Answer (score 0):

In case if you have environment variables set in your current terminal and just have it exported to the `systemctl` with `sudo`, you can use,

```
sudo -E  systemctl import-environment <LIST OF ENVIRONMENTS TO BE AVAILABLE FOR SERVICE>
```