# Environment variable in systemd given by a program

Tags: linux, systemd, environment-variables

Reading the documentation [at this link](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#Environment=) I can easily add a compile-time known variable within a systemd service, for example

```
Environment="VARIABLE=content"
```

So that

```
echo $VARIABLE
```

Is "content"

But what about the case I would need such VARIABLE be given by a program, i.e. /home/user/myprogram? Is there any way to make that Environment tag to fetch that program standard output?

Comment: Not sure, so I'm just dropping a comment here. It seems not to be possible; some alternatives I see are 1) setting variables in `ExecStart` ([example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/324035/315749)); 2) use `systemd.environment-generator` - it won't set _per-unit_ variables, but note that the environment of each unit is available via D-Bus anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what are you asking for. But could your program generate an environment file, which you can then load via `EnvironmentFile=`?